# Stable for n*8 cycles property

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I am learning SVA and trying to get my head around this check: data can only change every 8 cycles.

I know I can do that check by adding a counter that counts clock cycles and checking against it that way:

```
bit[2:0] count;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    count++;
end

change_n8cycles: assert property (@(posedge clk) $changed(data) |-> count == 0);
```

However, I'm interested in a way to do that with only SVA. So far, I was thinking of something like that (which doesn't compile)

```
property change_n8cycles(valid, ready, data);
    @(posedge clk)
    $changed(data) |=> $stable(data)[*7] ##1 ($stable(data)[*8])[0:$] ##0 $changed(data);
endproperty : change_n8cycles
```

I feel there is an elegant way using an approach similar; or using recursive properties. However, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to use local variable in order to verify that

```
property change_n8cycles(valid, ready, data);
int lv_cnt;
@(posedge clk)
($changed(data), lv_cnt=0) ##1 ($stable(data), lv_cnt=lv_cnt+1)[*1:$] ##1 $changed(data) |-> lv_cnt == 8;
endproperty
```

Or use some modeling layer

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if($changed(data))
    count=0;
  else
    count++;
end

property change_n8cycles(data);
  @(posedge clk)
  $changed(data) |-> $past(count) == 8;
endproperty
```

Comment: The local variable is *almost* exactly what I was looking for. It fails to detect when data changes 2 cycles in a row. I figure 2 fixes, what do you think? bit[2:0] cnt; ($changed(data), cnt=0) ##1 ($stable(data), cnt++)[*0:$] ##1 $changed(data) |-> cnt == 7; or ($changed(data), cnt=0) |=> ($stable(data), cnt++)[*1:$] ##1 $changed(data) ##0 cnt == 7;

Comment: Can you be more precise about your requirements : 
Data can changes either in 2 cyles or 8 cycles ?